# Android Clear External Image Cache On Exit

Tags: android, caching

How do execute Clear(); in FileCache.class from another activity. I'm showing small parts of my codings. My objective is to clear the external cached file on every exit. Can anyone please show me how it is done. Thanks

FileCache.class

```
public class FileCache {

    private File cacheDir;

    public FileCache(Context context){
        //Find the dir to save cached images
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
        else
            cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();
    }

    public File getFile(String url){
        //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
        String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        //Another possible solution (thanks to grantland)
        //String filename = URLEncoder.encode(url);
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
        return f;

    }

    public void clear(){
        File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
        if(files==null)
            return;
        for(File f:files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

MyMainActivity.class

```
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Do you want to exit?")
                   .setCancelable(false)
                   .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                           Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                           intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                           intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                           startActivity(intent);
                           new clear();  //<<--- How do i Call clear(); in FileCache.class
                           System.exit(0);
                       }
                   })
                   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                       }
                   });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

    }
```

Comment: check this hope it will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557570/solution-for-cleaning-an-image-cache-directory-on-the-sd-card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                               intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                               intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                               startActivity(intent);
                               FileCache loader = new FileCache(null);
                               loader.clear();  
                               System.exit(0);
                           }
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
    new  FileCache( MyMainActivity.this ).clear();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you have implemented the solution for [Lazy load of images in Android](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList).

There is already clearCache() method given in ImageLoader class:

```
 public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
```

So you can clear the cache by calling clearCache() method as below:

```
ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(mContext);
imgLoader.clearCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a reference to the FileCache object. I suppose you create it in the `onCreate()` from the activity. If so, make the FileCache an attribute from the activity. That way, you can call `myFileCacheReference.clear()` from the `onBackPressed()`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private FileCache myFileCacheRef;

  public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    //standard stuff
    myFileCacheRef = new FileCache();
  }

  public void onBackPressed() {
    myFileCacheRef.clear();
  }
}
```

something like this should work.